# Use of a function inside of a table

Tags: functions, matrix, list-manipulation

I have a function that I want to generate a square matrix whose entries are run from 1,...,n and whose i,jth entry is f(i,j) for some function f. My code that I have right now is
`genMat[n_, f_[x_, y_]] := Table[f[i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}]`, but if I set `f[x_,y_]:=x*y`, then `genMat[4,f[x,y]]` evaluates to `{{2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}`, the matrix generated from adding the values together as opposed to multiplying them. It does this for all other n. Anybody know what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Something is weird... maybe you have old definitions lingering. I suggest restarting the kernel and trying again.

Comment: Yeah, I retried it the next day and my method ended up working. Must’ve just been a weird bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recommend that you look at [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

genMat[n_Integer?Positive, f_] := Array[f, {n, n}]

genMat[4, f]

(* {{f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3], f[1, 4]}, {f[2, 1], f[2, 2], f[2, 3], 
  f[2, 4]}, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2], f[3, 3], f[3, 4]}, {f[4, 1], f[4, 2], f[4, 3], 
  f[4, 4]}} *)

genMat[4, Times]

(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 9, 12}, {4, 8, 12, 16}} *)

genMat[4, #1^2 - 3*#2 &]

(* {{-2, -5, -8, -11}, {1, -2, -5, -8}, {6, 3, 0, -3}, {13, 10, 7, 4}} *)
```